# How to create a packet which contains two images and two strings and send it via post method in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, base64, http-post

I have two images and two strings which have been converted to base64 strings and I wish to send them as packet using POST method. Should i concatenate the base64 strings or is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)? It can do a lot of things.

It can send POST parameters, images etc. Check out the "How to use it" section, it includes the sample codes.